# Override claims' key names used in JWTs in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token, asp.net-core-2.2

It is considered best practice not to leak implementation details to a system's clients. For example, not to respond with "Powered by foo" headers, etc.

The `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes` contains all sort of Microsoft-centric schemas which are a tipoff that one is using ASP.NET Core.

e.g., `Role` claim is: `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"`.

So:

- Is there an alternative approach to encoding JWTs to avoid this problem? (without having to custom code the entire auth layer).
- Specifically for the role claim, can its key be renamed somehow? The runtime provides useful auto-detection and use in Identity. I'd like to continue using this functionality, just somehow rename the claim's key.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bit far fetched as these types are from the older [WIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows-identity-foundation/ee727097(v=msdn.10)). So they don't point to asp.net core.

You can use alternative names. In the authority add claims (instead of roles) in order to set the claim type. Where claim type for role could be 'role'.

In order to map the claim, configure the resource:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(c =>
    {
        c.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        c.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    })
```

But the 'problem' remains that a JWT a public token is. The only way to really hide this kind of information is to not put it in the token and choose for a different design.

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately the JWT still shows the role claim's key as `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"`. Thanks though!

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing it correctly, but from what I understand this doesn't change the name of the role claim. However instead of roles I could use claims, and name the role claim whatever I want - however in that case I can't rely on Identity to automatically wire up the authorization for me. Maybe I don't understand your solution?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that roles are added as claims, as is in fact what already happens. There are no roles but claims of role-type. If Identity isn't adding the claims automatically for you then you may have to add some code, e.g. implement the IUserClaimStore. Also make sure the claim type is included when creating the token. The claims may be filtered or simply ignored, but that depends on the design.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but that means re-implementing core Identity functionality, which is diffuclt (and what I wanted to avoid). Thanks for your advice though!

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced same issue, here is my solution

```
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

foreach (var role in roles)
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    claims.Add(new Claim("roles", role));
}
```

with "ClaimTypes.Role" also add as "roles". This works for me.

Comment: it doesn't work for the "email" type, it returns nothing. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create your claims yourself:

```
List<Claim> claims = new()
            {
                new Claim("name", userModel.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userModel.Email),
                new Claim("email", userModel.Email),
                new Claim("id", userModel.Id),
            };
```

And then add them to your Token. And they will have those keys defined in your token.

I had an issue with the "email" one, not being passed to a protected route, but this is another problem.. I may have found a solution for.